# How to dynamically assign color to FullCalendar event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fullcalendar

I am attempting to implement a feature in a FullCalendar selectable demo that enables the user to dynamically change the color of each new calendar event using the HTML color picker. The user should be able to select a unique color for each event. In the current setup, for example, the first event generated takes whatever color value is selected in color picker. The issue, however, is that the first event changes to whatever color is selected for the second event. The second (and subsequent) events(s) should all have unique colors. I feel like I am close on this, but am getting stuck. Suggestions?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: "prev,next today",
      center: "title",
      right: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay"
    },
    defaultView: "month",
    navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: false,
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events

    select: function(start, end) {
      var title = prompt("Event Content:");
      var eventData;
      if (title) {
        eventData = {
          title: title,
          start: start,
          end: end
        };
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("renderEvent", eventData, true); // stick? = true
      }
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    },

    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      element
        .find(".fc-content")
        .prepend("<span class='closeon material-icons'>&#xe5cd;</span>");
      element.find(".closeon").on("click", function() {
        $("#calendar").fullCalendar("removeEvents", event._id);
      });

      let color = $("#colorPicker").val();
      element.css("background-color", color);    
    },

    eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent) {
      var title = prompt("Edit Event Content:", calEvent.title);
      calEvent.title = title;
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("updateEvent", calEvent);

    },    
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<span><input type='color' id='colorPicker'></span>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 40px 10px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar {
  max-width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#wrap {
  width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.closeon {
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

dependencies:

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/3.9.0/fullcalendar.min.css
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the color in the `select` callback:

```
eventData = {
  title: title,
  start: start,
  end: end, 
  color: $("#colorPicker").val()
}
```

and get rid of all the `eventRender: function()` etc code. That callback runs for *every* event on the calendar (even if you only add one new event, they all get re-rendered because the calendar has to be able change other events e.g. if there's an overlap or something). That's why you're seeing the colour change on all previously created events as well.

P.S. This documentation shows you how you can set the colour when creating an event, (rather than messing with the HTML, which can anyway be unreliable since events can be rendered in different ways in different circumstances): https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object

Answer (score 0):

When a user clicks on an event you can change the color in two ways.

1. as seen here https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick

```
var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {

  eventClick: function(info) {
    alert('Event: ' + info.event.title);
    alert('Coordinates: ' + info.jsEvent.pageX + ',' + info.jsEvent.pageY);
    alert('View: ' + info.view.type);

    // change the border color just for fun
    info.el.style.borderColor = 'red';
  }

});
```

2. Outside of the calendar function you can do something like this. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-getEventById
   set the property you want https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Event-setProp

```
        const event = calendar.getEventById(eventId);

        event.setProp("color", newEventColor);
```

To Make all the other events a random color, could try something like this

```
        
        calendar.removeAllEvents();
        const newEventsWithRandomColor = [];

        for(event of allOtherEvents){

            event = {
                id: event.id,
                title: event.title,
                start: event.start,
                allDay : true,
                color : randomColorFunction();
            
            };
            newEventsWithRandomColor.push(event);
        }

        fullCalendar.addEventSource(newEventsWithRandomColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this from **Controller**. here i am defining 2 things . 1) **color** 2) **className**.

If you want change only **background-color** then you can do it from `'color'=>'red'` or if you want to change something then you can define `className=>'eventHoiday'`

After that no need to change in your JS code.

```
 $events[] = array(
                    'id' => $driverBooking->id,
                    'booking_id'=> $driverBooking->id,
                    'color' => $color,     // an optional value !
                   'className'=> 'EventHoliday'  // an optional value !
                );
```