# How to add an image to an event on Vue FullCalendar? imageurl returns undefined

Tags: laravel, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm trying to add dynamically an image to the FullCalendar events with Vue. But first of all, I'm testing with a static data and the image doesn't show up.

This is what I'm trying to do after several research:

```
<template>
...
<FullCalendar 
                    defaultView="timeGridWeek" 
                    header="null"
                    :slotDuration="slotDuration"
                    :plugins="calendarPlugins"
                    @dateClick="handleDateClick"
                    :allDaySlot="false"
                    :columnHeaderFormat='columnHeaderFormat'
                    :hiddenDays="hiddenDays"
                    :themeSystem="themeSystem"
                    :minTime="minTime"
                    :maxTime="maxTime"
                    :contentHeight="contentHeight"
                    :events="tutor_applications_not_scheduled"
                    :config="config"
                    @eventRender="eventRender"
                />
...
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'
import bootstrapPlugin from '@fullcalendar/bootstrap'

export default {
    components: {
        FullCalendar
    },

    data(){
        return {
            tutor_application_setup_id: this.$route.params.tutor_application_setup_id,

            loading: false,

            uri: '/tutor-applications-schedules/',

            calendarPlugins: [dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin, bootstrapPlugin], 
            slotDuration: '01:00',
            columnHeaderFormat: {weekday:'long'},
            hiddenDays: [], //[0,6] - Sunday and Saturday
            themeSystem: 'bootstrap',
            minTime: '10:00', // will be dynamic
            maxTime: '17:00', // will be dynamic
            contentHeight: 'auto',
            config: {
                timeFormat: 'h(:mm) a',
                eventClick: function(event) {
                    if (event.url) {
                    location.replace(event.url);
                    return false;
                    }
                }
            },

            tutor_applications_schedules: [],
            tutor_applications_not_scheduled: [],
            tutor_applications_scheduled: [],

            errors: [],

        }
    },

    methods: {

        handleDateClick(arg){
            alert(arg.date)
        },

        loadTutorApplicationsSchedules(){
            axios.get(this.uri + this.tutor_application_setup_id).then(response=>{
                this.tutor_applications_schedules = response.data.tutor_applications_schedules
                this.loadTutorApplicationsNotScheduled()
                this.loading = true
            });
        },

        loadTutorApplicationsNotScheduled(){

            // this.tutor_applications_schedules.forEach(schedule => {
                // if(!schedule.is_scheduled){
                    this.tutor_applications_not_scheduled.push({
                        title: 'TEST TITLE',
                        start: '2019-05-22 10:00',
                        end: '2019-05-22 13:00',
                        imageurl: '/images/profile/1557196883.png'
                    });
                // }
            // });

        },

        eventRender: function(event, eventElement) {
            console.log(event) // returning everything
            console.log(event.imageurl) // returning undefined
            if (event.imageurl) {
                eventElement.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='" + event.imageurl +"' width='16' height='16'>");
            }
        },

        loadTutorApplicationsScheduled(){

        },

        moment: function (date) {
            return moment(date)
        },

    },

    mounted(){
        this.loadTutorApplicationsSchedules()
    }
}
</script>
```

The result returns only the time and the title in the correct date.

I also tried to insert the img tag to the `title` attribute, and changed the eventRender, like below:

```
...
title: '<img src="/images/profile/1557196883.png" />TEST TITLE',
...
```

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
            var title = element.find( '.fc-title' );
            title.html(title.text());
        },
```

It's returning the html tag as string, like `<img src="/images/profile/1557196883.png" />TEST TITLE`.

**Some of my dependencies are:**

```
"vue": "^2.5.17",
"@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/core": "^4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^4.1.0",
        "@fullcalendar/vue": "^4.1.1",
        "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
        "vue-full-calendar": "^2.7.0",
```

I don't know which approach to follow anymore. Any help? Thank you.

**UPDATE**

I realized that some params has changed ([Full Calendar Updates](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3#event-rendering)) and I changed my eventRender function, and now I can read the imageurl. However, I'm stuck how in Vue to find a tag and prepend with my image tag.

My code now is like this:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
            console.log(info) // returning everything
            console.log(info.event.extendedProps.imageurl) // returning the image path correctly
            if (info.event.extendedProps.imageurl) {
                info.el.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='" + info.event.extendedProps.imageurl +"' width='16' height='16'>"); // this line is the problem now
            }
        },
```

It's returning the error `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: info.el.find is not a function"`, and I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For whom it may concern :), [this thread helped me](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/2919), and I figured out what to do. I changed my eventRender to this:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
            if (info.event.extendedProps.imageurl) {
                info.el.firstChild.innerHTML = info.el.firstChild.innerHTML + "<img src='" + info.event.extendedProps.imageurl +"' width='40' height='40'>";
            }
        },
```

In this case, I can be even more flexible like:

```
info.el.firstChild.innerHTML = "<div><h4><a href='#'>"+ info.event.title +"</a></h4><img src='" + info.event.extendedProps.imageurl +"' width='40' height='40'></div>";
```

etc.

I hope this can help someone else!

Answer (score 0):

Define a variable in data as `imageURL: "",`

Define img tag in html where you want to show it as

```
<img v-if="imageURL!=''" :src="imageURL" width='16' height='16'>
```

Your renderer function

```
eventRender: function(info) {
    if (info.event.extendedProps.imageurl) {
        this.imageURL = info.event.extendedProps.imageurl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer, but this solution won't solve my problem. I'm using the FullCalendar component, so the event is created dynamically, which means that I can't set a place to insert the img tag. Because that, I would like to know how to find a specific tag, in this case ```div.fc-content``` and prepend with the image tag in Vuejs. This ```info.el.find("div.fc-content").prepend("<img src='" + info.event.extendedProps.imageurl +"' width='16' height='16'>");``` doesn't work in Vuejs with Vue FullCalendar.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did mind by putting this function into methods

```js
eventRender(info) {
 info.el.firstChild.innerHTML = `
     <a class="rounded-lg fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event f-start fc-end">
        <div class="h-12">
           <span class="fc-title text-white flex ml-3">
              <img class="img-circle avatar-small h-8 w-8 p-1" src="${info.event.extendedProps.imageurl}">
             <span class="ml-3 self-center font bold">${info.event.extendedProps.username}</span>
           </span>
        </div>
     </a>
                `
},
```

Now to change color dynamically for each event I did it from Laravel Resource

```php
  'backgroundColor'    => $this->status === 1 ? '#48BB78'  : '#F6E05E'
```

Tried to use :class inside the eventRender and didn't work.
So you can just send in the API the color you want based on a condition instead and perform the operation on laravel.

Comment: I don't know why yours didn't work with class. I'm using class without any problem. Example: `info.el.firstChild.innerHTML = info.el.firstChild.innerHTML + "<div class='ribbon-wrapper'><span>" + props.name + "</span></div>"`

Comment: I tried this and didn't work `:class="${this.eventClass(info.event.extendedProps.status)}"`

Comment: you may find this other thread interesting as well
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809647/how-to-dynamically-assign-color-to-fullcalendar-event