# Unable to change background color dynamically

Tags: css, fullcalendar, knockout-3.0, fullcalendar-4

I have a function: loadCalendar, that renders the calendar. My events have a property 'Color' which I'm trying to use to change the background color. The console log returns data such as: #007777 Please advise.

```
    loadCalendar: function () {
    var resId = "";
    var eventObj = [];
    var bcolor = "";
    viewModel.calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(viewModel.calendarEl, {
        plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid'],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        defaultDate: calendarDate,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
        },
        events: viewModel.eventsByLocation(),
        //events: viewModel.events(),
        eventClick: function (info) {
            var id = info.event.id;
            viewModel.ReservationEdit(id);
        },

        eventRender: function (info) {
            resId = info.event.id;
            eventObj = ko.utils.arrayFilter(viewModel.events(), function (item) {
                return item.id == resId;
            });
            bcolor = eventObj[0].Color;
            bcolor = '#' + bcolor;
            console.log(bcolor);
            backgroundColor: bcolor;
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
},
```

Comment: The line `backgroundColor: bcolor;` doesn't do anything. If you want to change the colour like this, then you have to actually change the style property of the HTML element (i.e. `info.el`)

Comment: But to be honest if you want to set the colour of an event, you can just set it on your event object using a property which fullCalendar recognises and it will do it for you automatically. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing - you have a choice of `color` (not `Color`!), `backgroundColor`, `borderColor` and `textColor` depending what you want to change.

Comment: Above you said "backgroundColor: bcolor;" doesn't do anything - that's my point. It seems to me you should be able to pass a variable here, instead of a literal such as '#007777'

Comment: `It seems to me you should be able to pass a variable here, instead of a literal such as '#007777' `...that's irrelevant. My point was that `backgroundColor: bcolor;` is not a command, it does not update anything or set any variables. You normally find that `x : y` syntax when you're declaring the properties of an object literal. When used by itself it's still valid JavaScript syntax (for some reason), but it doesn't actually achieve anything. Anyway did you read my second comment about a more sensible way to implement your requirement?

Comment: Yes and thank you. I can do it that way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809647/how-to-dynamically-assign-color-to-fullcalendar-event/69612699#69612699